# Is this possible with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to execute the following code, using AngularJS.
So far I got this:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat='(key,value) in dset'><span>{{key}}</span>
    <li ng-repeat="n in value"> {{ n }}</li> //DOES NOT WORK
 </li>
</ul>

dSet: { "something" : [ "abc, "def" ], "something2": ["abc","blah"] }
```

Basically I have a Map> and want to print this as in:
String1
   listValue1
   listValue2
   listValue3
   ...
String2
   listValue1
   listValue2

Please let me know if you have any thoughts on how to get this to work.

Comment: please provide data in dset.

Comment: Updated question with dset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your dset is...

```
$scope.dset = {a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6]};
```

If you want your list-items to be nested, use:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in dset"><span>{{key}}</span>
        <ul><li ng-repeat="v in val">{{v}}</li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you want your list-items not to be nested, use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat-start="(key, val) in dset"><span>{{key}}</span>
    <li ng-repeat="v in val" ng-repeat-end>{{v}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, initially didn't work because I was using old version of angular, after updating solutions above work. Appreciate the answer!